# Twilio IP Messaging API not working

Tags: javascript, api, ip, twilio, messaging

I just followed the instructions to setup and test it. I used Javascript API. When I tried to message using two tabs or two windows as mentioned in the docs it is not working. It throws error at sendMessage method being "undefined". when I console log it gets the correct message typed in the html element.

### As soon as I start localhost it throws following error. Any suggestions please.

Navigated to http://localhost:3000/

```
cds.twilio.com/v2/Streams:1 POST https://cds.twilio.com/v2/Streams 403 (Forbidden)
twilio-ip-messaging.min.js:198 IPMSG: failed to create session Object {status: 403, description: "Forbidden", body: "{"message":"Access forbidden","status":403}"}(anonymous function) @ twilio-ip-messaging.min.js:198
undefined:1 Uncaught (in promise) Object {status: 403, description: "Forbidden", body: "{"message":"Access forbidden","status":403}"}
undefined:1 Uncaught (in promise) Object {status: 403, description: "Forbidden", body: "{"message":"Access forbidden","status":403}"}
undefined:1 Uncaught (in promise) Object {status: 403, description: "Forbidden", body: "{"message":"Access forbidden","status":403}"}
twilio-ip-messaging.min.js:199 Twilsock connection closed by server []r._onSocketRejected @ twilio-ip-messaging.min.js:199d.create.callbacks.onsocketRejected @ twilio-ip-messaging.min.js:199e.doCallback @ twilio-ip-messaging.min.js:281e.afterThisEvent @ twilio-ip-messaging.min.js:281e.afterEvent @ twilio-ip-messaging.min.js:281transition @ twilio-ip-messaging.min.js:281(anonymous function) @ twilio-ip-messaging.min.js:281r.onmessage @ twilio-ip-messaging.min.js:199
```

Comment: This looks like you are not setting up your access token correctly so Twilio is not giving you access to the service. Can you share the code you are using to authenticate the API?

Comment: @philnash. Thanks. this is what i use:

Comment: I don't see anything! Probably best to update the question with this extra information.

Comment: @philnash Thanks. This is what I am using

' var ipmGrant = new IpMessagingGrant({
        serviceSid: process.env.TWILIO_IPM_SERVICE_SID,
        endpointId: endpointId
    });

    // Create an access token which we will sign and return to the client,
    // containing the grant we just created
    var token = new AccessToken(
        process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID,
        process.env.TWILIO_API_KEY,
        process.env.TWILIO_API_SECRET
    );'

Comment: Are you using your production or test Account Sid? And how do you set the access token in the front end?

Comment: I am using Test account Sid. Front end not set yet.

Comment: @Indokiwi please accept this answer. It clearly works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

First of all, you will need to use your production Account Sid in order to get this to work.

[Twilio test credentials only work on certain parts of the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/test-credentials#supported-resources).

Once you have generated your token on the server side, you need to get it to the client side and authenticate your client like this:

```
accessManager = new Twilio.AccessManager(token);
messagingClient = new Twilio.IPMessaging.Client(accessManager);
```

Take a look at the [IP Messaging quick start code to see an example of how it is done](https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/ipm-quickstart-node/blob/master/public/index.js#L55-L59). [The full instructions for the quick start guide can be found here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging/guides/quickstart-js).

Let me know if that helps at all.